# Handling exception in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, tkinter

```
class Application(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        Tk.report_callback_exception = self.show_error

    def show_error(self, *args):
        err = traceback.format_exception(*args)
        messagebox.showerror('Title', f"{err[-1]}")
```

When an exception is raised I will have something like this:

[image: ZeroDivisionError]

If a create a simple Class Exception from Exception to easily pass description:

```
class Pingu_Exception(Exception):
    pass
```

if i except a ZeroDivisionError and Raise my error(Pingu_Exception) from an imported python file
I can easily catch it

```
try:
        x = 4 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError:
        raise Pingu_Exception("Description")
```

[image: Pingu_Exception]

The problem is when I try to catch imported Exception.
For example:

```
from requests.exceptions import ReadTimeout


class Woocommerce_api(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.orders_endpoint = "orders/"
        self.customers_endpoint = "customers/"
        self.products_endpoint = "products/"

    def __api_json(self, endpoint):

        try:
            wcapi = API(
                url="https://www.xxxx.it",
                consumer_key=self.consumer_key,
                consumer_secret=self.consumer_secret,
                wp_api=True,
                version="wc/v1",
                query_string_auth=True,
                timeout=3
            )
            return wcapi

        except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
            raise Pingu_Exception('"Timeout error\nIl server non risponde\nRiprova nuovamente')
```

This is what I catch:

[image: request exception]

but if a try to raise an requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout, in his same function, it will work:

```
def __api_json(self, endpoint):
    try:
        raise requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout

        wcapi = API(
            url="https://www.slow-sud.it",
            consumer_key=self.consumer_key,
            consumer_secret=self.consumer_secret,
            wp_api=True,
            version="wc/v1",
            query_string_auth=True,
            timeout=3
        )
        return wcapi
except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
        raise Pingu_Exception('"Timeout error\nIl server non risponde\nRiprova nuovamente')
        return False
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting problem. I tried to reproduce it locally. Sadly, it would take some time to setup this with the given information. Could you please try to present a minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: `wcapi = API(...)` just creates the API instance and does not make the request at all (`wcapi.get()` does the request), so it won't generate the `requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout` exception.  The exception caught should be somewhere else.